# Can an OBD2 tester do a battery load test?

Tags: battery, obd-ii, diagnostics

[This Autophix device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RTKTY82) device was suggested by a [review](https://bestreviews.com/best-battery-load-testers) as the best of five battery testers.  The text implied that includes testing cranking amps.  But it can only connect to the computer—has no way to connect to the battery.

Can I actually use it to rule out the battery for an RV not starting?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot do a battery load test. If it could don't use it. The wires to the OBD ll port can't handle it. In theory it might be able to do a battery cunductive test, but in my opinion, even if it could it would definitely be an unreliable test. Best (and as far as I'm concerned only) way to test a battery is at the battery.

Comment: _IF_ it can do a load test, it could not be “through” the OBD port.  The only way would be if the _computer_ has a way to do it and report the results to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to gather the current voltage delivered via the OBD2 port (12V +- something, there is even the `ATRV` command for that), a load test is out of scope through the port.

Comment: So, the Amazon advert is false advertising and the review comments are incorrect?